# OpenSSL dgst: Error opening signature file

Tags: linux, bash, openssl

I'm attempting to verify a trust-store that's contained in a .zip file. I've been able to validate it within my workstation (which has ubuntu with `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`).

```
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -verify <(openssl x509 -sha1 -in signature-certificate.pem -noout -pubkey) -signature truststore.zip.dgst truststore.zip
```

As said, this works on my workstation, however, running this on my server I get this error:

```
Error opening signature file truststosre.zip.dgst
3069867216:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:165:fopen('truststosre.zip.dgst','rb')
3069867216:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:168:
```

I should mention that the 'server' has `OpenSSL 1.0.2 22 Jan 2015` and a `/bin/bash` version of `14.3.30(1)-release`

Could anyone shed any light on why my server isn't validating the same file-pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the OpenSSL meant that it couldn't find the file you had specified:

```
3069867216:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:165:fopen('truststosre.zip.dgst','rb')
```

This can happen if you're running openssl without setting environmental variables or when openssl is launched from another process.

First of all, try specifying full path to your `truststosre.zip.dgst` file, if it won't help - you should check if the user, who launched openssl (i.e. if it is launched inside a PHP-script, it would be the `www-data` user) has enough rights to access the file.

The command for `www-data` user will be:

```
sudo -u www-data cat /path/to/truststosre.zip.dgst
```

If the user hasn't got enough permissions - you'll get `Permission denied` error.

P.S. A closer look reveals a possible ingenious solution, which involves fixing the most widespread type of IT-related error - mistype:

When you are trying to verify the file on your PC it is called `truststore.zip.dgst`, while on remote sever you access `truststo**s**re.zip.dgst`. Try to remove that **"s"** and I bet it will start working right away!

Comment: First of all, I've made sure to match the runtime-user and my personal account, so I don't think it's the user, although the ENV setup is probably something I need to look at.

But second of all....holy crap! `openssl dgst -verify pubkey -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -signature truststo**.zip.dgst truststore.zip` == `Verified OK` how!? and why!?! I virtually copy and pasted the command from one machine to the next???

I'm so confused right now!!

Comment: ok. I see the typo. Dang, I seriously thought I had a legitimate, technical bug for you guys!!!